# Erro no Model AppML

Tags: javascript, html, aplicação-web

Estou tentado aprender AppML, para prototipação e quem sabe uso em produção.

Mas enfrento o seguinte erro: Error in Model: model_tarefas

Tenho um arquivo model_tarefas.js na para data com o seguinte conteúdo:

```
{
    "rowsperpage" : 10,
    "database" : {
        "connection" : "dbtarefas",
        "sql" : "SELECT id, descricao, finalizado, data_finalizado FROM tarefas",
        "orderby" : "id"
    }
}
```

O mesmo está de acordo com a pequena documentação existente.

Dentro da seção principal tenho o código:

```
<section class="w3-container" appml-data="data/appml.php?model=model_tarefas">
```

Quando uso uma variável local como fonte de dados, dá tudo certo, mas quando chamo pelo banco de dados, dá problema.